# Type-safe database access in Scala.js on node.js?

Tags: node.js, scala, slick, electron, scala.js

I want to build a cross platform [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) app with an embedded SQLite database. Scala.js would be running on both UI and "backend" of the app, which is an embedded node.js server. JVM is not involved in this setup in any way. So, Scala.js will need to talk to said SQLite database.

Scala has [Squeryl](http://squeryl.org/), [Slick](http://slick.lightbend.com/) and a few other libraries for talking to SQL databases in a type-safe way. Those libraries [don't work](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1313) in Scala.js on node.js because they use `java.sql` which is [not implemented](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/tree/master/javalib/src/main/scala/java) in Scala.js.

How can I talk to the database (simple SQLite is enough) in a type-safe way from Scala.js?

My best guess right now is to write a type-safe Scala.js facade for some node.js database access library, perhaps using [Autowire](https://github.com/lihaoyi/autowire)? Not sure if that is a good approach, or even possible. Any pointers welcome.

Comment: "My best guess [...]" Yep, that's it: leverage a Node.js database access library. Autowire, though ... probably not. That is only useful if both sides talk Scala. But your database doesn't talk Scala; it talks SQL.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. Could be a fun introduction to Scala's type system.